# I want all pregnancy_pp cases whose grandparent case_id is the same as my family_id

Tags: commcare

We are trying to get a warning label to display if someone is registering a pregnant client in a family that already contains a pregnant woman. Clients are child cases of family cases. Pregnancy cases are extension cases of clients.

Answer (score 1):

The expression is:

```
count(instance('casedb')/casedb/case[selected(join(" ", instance('casedb')/casedb/case[index/parent = instance('commcaresession')/session/data/case_id_load_family_0]/@case_id), index/host)][@status = "open"][@case_type = "pregnancy_pp"]) > 0 and /data/pregnancy_pp/pregnant = 'yes'
```

To explain:

```
instance('casedb')/casedb/case[index/parent = instance('commcaresession')/session/data/case_id_load_family_0]/@case_id
```

This part gives the case_ids of the clients in the current family
However, it is not structured like a space-separated list.  It's structured XML.  So we couldn't use `selected()` on that.
So we first converted the structured XML to a space separated list with `join(" ", xxxx)`
Then we were able to stick that into the `selected(xxx, index/host)`.